# Knockout.js passing viewmodels value to multiple page

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am new to Knockout.js, i have 2 viewModel `EmployeeviewModel` and `DepartmentViewModel`, i am binding my first view using `EmployeeviewModel` its working perfect, now i need make click so i can navigate to second page which is department and in frist i need to display click `EmployeeName` and his department, secondly i need to display all the `EmployeeName` related to that department how to achive this, how i can pass my first page value to second page display related to `departmentID`.

```
  function EmployeeViewModel()
  {
   var self =this;
   var Allemployee =ko.observableArray([])
   self.getEmployeedetails=function ()
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: baseUrl + 'xxx/xxxxxx',
    success: function (data) {
        self.Allemployee($.map(data, function (item) {
                return new EmployeeModel(item);
            }));
    },
    error: function (error) {
    }
});
     self.getDepartment=function()
     {
       //here i need to navigate to Department page with all department ID
      }
}

function EmployeeModel(data)
{
    var self =this;
    self.employeeName = ko.observable(data.employeeName )
    self.employeeMobile= ko.observable(data.employeeMobile)
    self.employeeemail = ko.observable(data.employeeemail )
    self.employeedepartmentId= ko.observable(data.employeedepartmentId)
}

 function DepartmentViewModel()
  {
   var self =this;
   var AllDepartmentemployee =ko.observableArray([])
   self.getEmployeedetails=function ()
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: baseUrl + 'xxx/xxxxxx',
    success: function (data) {
        self.AllDepartmentemployee ($.map(data, function (item) {
                return new DepartmentModel(item);
            }));
    },
    error: function (error) {
    }
});

}

 function DepartmentModel (item)
{
     self.departmentId= ko.observable(data.departmentId)
     self.departmentName=ko.observable(data.departmentName)
     self.employeeName=ko.observable(data.employeeName)
}
  var viewModel=new EmployeeViewModel()
   ko.applyBindings(EmployeeViewModel,document.getElementById("employeeDetails"))

 var viewModel 2=new DepartmentViewModel()
   ko.applyBindings(viewModel,document.getElementById("department"))


 //html//
 //First view
 <div data-role="view" id="employeeDetails">
        <ul>
         <li>
            <div data-bind="text:employeeName"></div>
            <div data-bind="text:employeeMobile"></div>
            <div data-bind="text:employeeemail "></div>
            <div data-bind="text:employeedepartmentId"></div>
            <a href="#" data-bind="click:getDepartment"></a>
        </li>
        </ul>
 <div>

   //second View
  <div data-role="view" id="department">
      <div data-bind="text:employeeName">

      <div>
      <div data-bind="text:departmentName">

      <div>
       <ul data-bind:"foreach:AllDepartmentemployee">
       <li>
          <div data-bind="text:employeeName">
          <div data-bind="text:departmentName"></div>
        </li>
       <ul>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a `Main view model` and have two `sub view models` for your `departments` and `employees`. Then every time you click on any employee you will have the `departmentId` then based on your logic you can either send a request to the server along with `Id` and get back all the employees under that department or you already have all departments and you just `filter` them based on `departmentId` that has been passed.

Below is an example how to handle: https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/124/

**HTML:**

```
<div data-role="view" id="employeeDetails">
        <ul >
         <li>
            <span  class="info">Name</span>
            <span  class="info">Mobile</span>
            <span class="info">Email</span>
            <span  class="info">Dept.NO</span>
          </li>
          <hr>
           <!-- ko foreach: AllEmployee -->
          <li>
            <span data-bind="text:EmployeeName" class="info"></span>
            <span data-bind="text:EmployeeMobile" class="info"></span>
            <span data-bind="text:EmployeeEmail " class="info"></span>
            <span data-bind="text:EmployeeDepartmentId" class="info"></span>
            <a href="#" data-bind="click:$parent.GetDepartment">Click</a>
          </li>
         <!-- /ko -->
        </ul>
 <div>

   //second View
<div data-role="view" id="department">
      <h1 data-bind="text:SelectedEmployeeName"></h1>
      <div data-bind="if:AllDepartmentEmployee().length > 0">
        <h3 data-bind ="text:AllDepartmentEmployee()[0].DepartmentName()"></h3>
      </div>
       <ul data-bind ="foreach:AllDepartmentEmployee">
         <li>
           <div data-bind="text:EmployeeName"></div>
          <!-- <div data-bind="text:DepartmentName"></div> -->        
           </li>
       <ul>
 <div>
```

**VM:**

```
var employeesList = [{
  employeeId : 1,
  employeeName:"Mike" ,
  employeeMobile :1234561 ,
  employeeEmail:"Mike@example.com",
  employeeDepartmentId:1},
  {
   employeeId : 2,
   employeeName:"Alex" ,
   employeeMobile :1234562 ,
   employeeEmail:"Alex@example.com",
   employeeDepartmentId:1
  },
  {
   employeeId : 3,
   employeeName:"Dave" ,
   employeeMobile :1234563 ,
   employeeEmail:"Dave@example.com",
   employeeDepartmentId:1
  },
  {
  employeeId : 4,
  employeeName:"Dani" ,
  employeeMobile :1234564 ,
  employeeEmail:"Dani@example.com",
  employeeDepartmentId:2},
  {
   employeeId : 5,
   employeeName:"Chris" ,
   employeeMobile :1234565 ,
   employeeEmail:"Chris@example.com",
   employeeDepartmentId:2
  },
  {
   employeeId : 6,
   employeeName:"Matt" ,
   employeeMobile :1234566 ,
   employeeEmail:"Matt@example.com",
   employeeDepartmentId:2
  }
 ]
 var departmentsList = [
   {departmentId:1,
    departmentName:"Dept #1",
    employeeName:"Mike"
   },
   {departmentId:1,
    departmentName:"Dept #1",
    employeeName:"Alex"
    },
   {departmentId:1,
    departmentName:"Dept #1",
    employeeName:"Dave"}
    ,
    {departmentId:2,
    departmentName:"Dept #2",
    employeeName:"Matt "
   },
   {departmentId:2,
    departmentName:"Dept #2",
    employeeName:"Dani"
    },
   {departmentId:2,
    departmentName:"Dept #2",
    employeeName:"Chris "}
 ]
function MainViewModel(){
   var self = this;
   self.AllEmployee = ko.observableArray([]);
   self.AllDepartmentEmployee= ko.observableArray([]);
   self.SelectedEmployeeName = ko.observable();
    self.LoadEmployees = function (){
    // Ajax goes here to load uncomment below
    // $.ajax({
    //    type: "GET",
    //  dataType: "json",
    //  url: baseUrl + 'xxx/xxxxxx',
    //  success: function (data) {
          self.AllEmployee($.map(employeesList, function (item) {
            return new EmployeeModel(item);
        }));
    //  },
    //  error: function (error) {
    //  }
    //});
    }
    self.GetDepartment = function(employee){
      self.SelectedEmployeeName(employee.EmployeeName())
      data = {departmentId:employee.EmployeeDepartmentId()}
     // $.ajax({
     //  type: "GET",
     //  data:data,
     //  dataType: "json",
     //   url: baseUrl + 'xxx/xxxxxx',
     //  success: function (data) {
          // HERE YOU MAY JUST GET THE  LIST OF EMPLOEES FOR THIS DEPARTMENT OR YOU GET ALL AND HERE YOU FILTER 
        self.AllDepartmentEmployee ($.map(departmentsList, function (item) {
            if(item.departmentId == employee.EmployeeDepartmentId()){
              return new DepartmentModel(item);
          }
        }));
    //  },
    //  error: function (error) {
    //  }
   // });
  }
 }
 function EmployeeModel(data){
    var self = this;
    self.EmployeeId = ko.observable(data.employeeId);
    self.EmployeeName = ko.observable(data.employeeName);
    self.EmployeeMobile= ko.observable(data.employeeMobile);
    self.EmployeeEmail = ko.observable(data.employeeEmail );
    self.EmployeeDepartmentId= ko.observable(data.employeeDepartmentId);
}
 function DepartmentModel (data){
    var self = this;
     self.DepartmentId = ko.observable(data.departmentId)
     self.DepartmentName = ko.observable(data.departmentName)
     self.EmployeeName = ko.observable(data.employeeName)
}
var viewModel = new MainViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
viewModel.LoadEmployees();
```